# Rails Testing: Fixtures, Factories, and Magic numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, yaml

I've got an application that needs quite a bit of data (1000s of records) to do appropriate testing.  The only way I've found to get a decent set of testable, sensible data is to use a **subset of my production DB**.  I've converted this to YAML fixtures in the normal `test/fixtures' location.

This works, but now I have a bunch of seemingly brittle tests and assertions that depend on their being a particular number of records that meet condition X...

example

```
def test_children_association
  p = Parent.find(1)
  assert_equal 18, p.children.count, "Parent.children isn't providing the right records"
end
```

This doesn't seem like a good idea to me, but **I'm not sure if there is a better / accepted  way** to test an application that needs a large hierarchy of data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Magic numbers in tests aren't an anti-pattern.  Your tests need to be so dead-simple that you don't need to *test* them.  This means you'll have some magic numbers.  This means that your tests will break when you change small bits of functionality.  This is good.

Fixtures have [some problems](http://www.floehopper.org/articles/2006/06/27/rails-fixtures-help-or-hindrance), but there are a few simple things you can do to make them easier to work with:

1. Only have baseline data in your fixtures, the sort of data that most of your tests need but don't care about.  This will involve a time investment up front, but it's better to take the pain early than write poor unit tests for the life of the project.
2. Add the data to be tested in the context of the test.  This improves readability of your tests and saves you from writing "make sure nobody messed up the fixtures" sanity checks at the beginning of your unit tests.

Comment: This in combination with the thoughtbot rails plugin Shoulda, makes it quite easy to run a setup and teardown on a subgroup of test methods, keeping your test code DRY.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd say is: what are you testing in that example? If it's an ordinary AR has_many association, then I wouldn't bother writing a test for it. All you're doing is testing that AR works.

A better example might be if you had a very complicated query or if there was other processing involved in getting the list of children records. When you get them back, rather than testing for a count you could iterate through the returned list and verify that the children match the criteria you're using.

Comment: Yeah, in that example it was just an ActiveRecord Association.  I've started using Shoulda which provides helpers like should_have_many :children this makes it a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

what I've found most useful in this situation is not using fixtures at all but rather construct the database objects on the fly like

```
def test_foo
   project = Project.create valid_project.merge(....)
   *do assertions here*
end
```

and in my test_helpers I'd have a bunch of methods:

```
def valid_project
   { :user_id => 23, :title => "My Project" }
end

def invalid_project
   valid_project.merge(:title => nil)
end
```

I found that the pain of having to build massive collections of test objects has led me naturally to design simpler and more versatile class structures.

Comment: This would be equivalent to (but a little less elegant than) using fixtures and then `Model.update_attributes` in the test, which is what DHH suggests: http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/2014/test-induced-design-damage.html

Answer (score 0):

Cameron's right:  What are you testing?

What sort of system needs 1000s of records present to test?  Remember, your tests should be as tiny as possible and should be testing application behavior.  There's no way it needs thousands of records for the vast majority of those tests.

For little bits of behavior tests where you need object relationships, consider mock objects.  You'll only be speccing out the exact minimum amount of behavior necessary to get your test to pass, and they won't hit the DB at all, which will amount to a huge performance gain in your test suite.  The faster it is to run, the more often people will run it.

Comment: After some optimization, I got the requirements down to only 150 or so records across 5 tables,  It's a data analysis application.

Answer (score 0):

I may have a unique situation here, but I really did need quite a few records for testing this app (I got it down to 150 or so).  I'm analyzing historical data and have numerous levels of `has_many`.  Some of my methods do custom SQL queries across several tables which I might end up modifying to use `ActiveRecord.find` but I needed to get the test running first.

Anyway, I ended up using some **ruby code to create the fixtures**.  The code is included in my `test_helper`; it checks the test DB to see if the data is stale (based on a time condition) and wipes and **recreates the records procedurally**.  In this case, creating it procedurally allows me to know what the data I'm testing for *SHOULD* be, which is **safer than using a subset of production data** and hoping the numbers I calculate the first time are what I should test for in the future.

I also moved to using [Shoulda](http://www.thoughtbot.com/projects/shoulda/) which along with many other useful things makes ActiveRecord Association testing as easy as:

```
should_have_many :children
should_belong_to :parent
```

Comment: So, you recreated the records based on production data whenever tests were run? Was it a success?